# Check if a given point is inside the convex hull of 4 points.

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polygons

Given 4 points (A,B,C,D) in a 2D plane, how do i check if a point M is inside the convex hull of those points?
Can i take the four triangles ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD and check if M is inside one of them?
Or do i have to compute the convex hull using Jarvis march? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convex hull can be constructed as only 2 triangles.

You could also try to evaluate the bilinear coordinates of M with respect of it and verify if they range in [0,1]²

Comment: What triangles do i choose though?

Comment: Make some drawing: basically there are 2 cases, ABCD is right ok, or it is twisted like a butterfly then use ABDC instead. Would you know how to derivate a criterion to detect the case ?

Comment: I am trying to implement a program that checks this. Veryfing for all 4 triangles would solve the problem, but it would be inefficient. I guess i have to check the orientation of ABC and BCD to detect the case?

Comment: oh, not homework, then ?

Comment: indeed for a twisted quadrilateral, there are 2 direct angles and 2 indirect angles, and the ones facing on any diagonal disagree. so, yes.

Comment: Thanks. So if i have the convex quadrilateral ABCD i check using the triangles ABC and ACD and in the case of a concave one i check using the triangles ABD and BCD?